# H4 font-size property missing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I inspect element using `Chrome Dev Tools` the default `font-size` property is missing for the `h4` tag. All the other tags like h1, h2, h3, h5, h6 are showing the `font-size` property.

See the screenshot [image]

I have checked the default style sheet for HTML 4, here also the `font-size` property is missing.

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html

```
h1              { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2              { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3              { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h4, p,
blockquote, ul,
fieldset, form,
ol, dl, dir,
menu            { margin: 1.12em 0 }
h5              { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6              { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
```

What might me the valid reason for this behavior?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no need to specify the default value for a property. In Chrome, H4 are the size of the default font. H1-H3 are scaled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the designer of the browser’s style sheet wanted to make the default font size of `h4` equal to `1em`, i.e. the font size of its parent. This makes it fit to the scale of heading font sizes. When `font-size` is not set for an element at all, it inherits the size from its parent, so the result is the same as it would be with `h4 { font-size: 1em }`. (Not in all circumstances, but in these. The browser’s default style sheet is lowest in the cascade, so a relevant setting in *any* other style sheet will override it.)

Note that the sample style sheet for HTML 4 in the CSS 2.1 specification is outdated and contain some odd settings that were never implemented in browsers, and many settings have been tuned later. The [Rendering](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html) section in HTML5 PR contains a much more modern description of typical (and more or less recommended) default settings in browsers. For clarity, it explicitly sets `font-size: 1.00em;` on `h4`.